# How to set access to symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony 4 and fosuserbundle.

I have a dynamic url where the language shortcut would be set. example.com/en

This would be the default url when user be logged in. But when they are not logged in then they would redirect to example.com/en/login

in the route.yaml I have the following route

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'

home:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

fos_user_security:
    prefix: /{_locale}
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_registration:
    prefix: /{_locale}/register
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"

fos_user_resetting:
    prefix: /{_locale}/resetting
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    prefix: /{_locale}/profile
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
```

and in the security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            # this firewall applies to all URLs
            pattern: ^/

            # but the firewall does not require login on every page
            # denying access is done in access_control or in your controllers
            anonymous: ~

            # This allows the user to login by submitting a username and password
            # Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            form_login:
                # fos user bundle handles the form login
                #provider: fos_userbundle
                # The route name that the login form submits to
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                # The name of the route where the login form lives
                # When the user tries to access a protected page, they are redirected here
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                # Secure the login form against CSRF
                # Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                # The route name the user can go to in order to logout
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                # The name of the route to redirect to after logging out
                target: homepage

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

But when I now try to open the site, I get always a permission denied error.

When i change the role in the second path from "ROLE_USER" to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, then the page would open, also with the link to "Login" the Loginpage would be open correct and I can login, but the page should be a "Login"-Only Page.

I think that I have to write something into the path of the access_control, but I don't get what I have to write there.

An when I set the access_denid_url, then it also didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Update:

Here I try the following settings:

```
access_denied_url:
    /[a-z]{2}/login
# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/[a-z]{2}/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

> > The file "config/packages/security.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: Unexpected characters near "/login$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your regex in `- { path: ^/[a-z]{2}/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

should be in quotes (either single or double) so do:

```
- { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/login$', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```